# allow to store up to 6 even numbers (press 99 to finish)

Tags: c

I'm doing a small program as exercise which allows to store up to six integer even numbers, or if the user wants to finish it just input 99, at the end of the program it shows the 6 saved numbers.

The problem is when is pressed 99, it goes out and show the array of 6 numbers as planned, however the last number of the array (array[5]) is always 99 and I can't find the reason why this is happening.

Below is the code of the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i; /*integer value*/
    int count;  /*even values counter defined as 6*/
    int array[5] ; /*array where we will save the values*/
    int  pos = 0; /*array position*/

    for (pos = 0; pos < 6; ++pos)
        array[pos] = 0;

    pos = 0;

    for (count = 6 ; count > 0 ; --count)
    {
        do 
        {
            puts("please write an even integer value or 99 to exit:");
            fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%d", &i);

            if ((i%2) == 0)
                array[pos++] = i;
                                   ;
        } while((i % 2) != 0 && i != 99);

        if (i == 99)
            count = 0;

    }


    printf("\n\nThe even integer values you wrote are:\n\n");

    for (pos = 0; pos <= 5; ++pos)
        printf(" %d  ", array[pos]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int array[5]` won't hold 6 numbers, and accessing `array[5]` invokes *undefined behavior*. An array of `[5]` is indexible from `0..4`, and holds **five** `int`; not six. Noteworthy, `fflush(stdin)` is non-standard; find another way to flush your input data.

Comment: fflush(stdin) I'll remove it. 

But regarding the array, I disagree, since when I input a total of 6 even numbers it definitely shows the 6th one which is array[5]. 

But anyways Do you think this may be causing to show 99 always on the last position?

Comment: Your confusing *observed* behavior with *defined* behavior. As-written your program is ill-formed, and invokes undefined behavior. The results are therefore, *without definition*. Disagree if you want, but you're breaking the rules. Without rules *anything* can happen, even occasionally, something you hoped would.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding I guess you were right. Thank you for the advice. 

declaring array[6] solved the problem. 

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like @WhozCraig commented, `int array[5]` won't hold the number of elements, and needs to be changed to `int array[6]`.

Comment: Post-incrementation is useless here.

Comment: @Quentin You're right, I forgot the order that it was executed in, I thought that it'd miss the 0th element. I'll edit to remove that.

Comment: +1. Regarding post-increment in the loop, unless you *need* the prior value expression, use pre-increment. Modern compilers won't care, and the resulting asm code will likely be the same, but there is a *chance* it will make a difference, and it *definitely* can make a difference when using complex post-vs-pre-increment operator overrides in languages like C++. Usually no difference in optimized C, but worth being a habit regardless. Use pre-increment unless you specifically *need* that prior value expression result.